# How do you know that a webview has some JS function ？

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

We know that Java can call js functions in the javafx webview in the form of ‘ 
  webView.getEngine().executeScript("setServerStatus('xxxxx')")   ’ , but sometimes when you switch HTML pages, it can't find a js function. In the background, i use threads to update the network status of the HTML page in real time , it sometimes reports the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setServerStatus
at com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:146)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1509)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:1005)
at com.gzhuiqun.adapter.Application.lambda$4(Application.java:370)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Does Java provide a way to determine whether a js function exists in the current HTML?
Or a more elegant way to do it?
In webview html5, the normal js monitoring network status function is invalid.

Comment: This might have several reasons. But to determine which, we need a bit more information. Are you sure the webpage is done loading? (checked via workloader). Second, is this based around a javacript callback (i.e. Is the update event triggered from the html/javascript side), or is it purely an `executeScript` call?

Comment: *workloader = loadWorker

Comment: [mcve] please ..